# Hello World Module On Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1

I am trying to create a simnple Hello World Module in Magento 1.9 but i keep getting 404 error.

Please what am i doing wrong?

Below is my code :

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Practice_ControllerTest>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Practice_ControllerTest>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test_controller>
                <use>Standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Practice_ControllerTest</module>
                    <frontName>requestflowtest</frontName>
                </args>
            </test_controller>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Practice_ControllerTest_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
    }

}
```

I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Which URL do you call ?

Comment: I called this url: http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/requestflowtest/

Comment: For some reason my codes are been cut off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend router is not properly declared, you need to replace:

```
        <test_controller>
            <use>Standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Practice_ControllerTest</module>
                <frontName>requestflowtest</frontName>
            </args>
        </test_controller>
```

With:

```
        <requestflowtest>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Practice_ControllerTest</module>
                <frontName>requestflowtest</frontName>
            </args>
        </requestflowtest>
```

Notice the lowercase "s" in "standard"

Comment: Thanks Mate.. I appreciate.. Please could you guide me on how to format codes in here?

Comment: @user2531490 Select your code and click the preformatted text icon in the WYSIWYG (5th icon from the left)